# Why does `childNodes` return a number larger than I expect?

Tags: javascript, html

Could you please look at [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WADsy/), and tell me why the number '11' is alerted rather than '5' (the number of `<li>` elements)?

From jsFiddle:

#### HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>milk</li>
    <li>butter</li>
    <li>eggs</li>
    <li>orange juice</li>
    <li>bananas</li>
</ul>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var list_items = list.childNodes;
alert(list_items.length);
```

Answer (score 14):

The `childNodes`, depending on the browser used, will return the text nodes, as well as the tags that are children of the parent node.  So technically, the whitespace in between the `<li>` tags will also be counted among the `childNodes`.

To avoid processing them, you may check that `nodeType != 3`.  [Here is a list of node types.](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml)

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var list_items = list.childNodes;
var li_items = [];
for (var i=0; i<list_items.length; i++) {
  console.log(list_items[i].nodeType);

  // Add all the <li> nodes to an array, skip the text nodes
  if (list_items[i].nodeType != 3) {
    li_items.push(list_items[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Michael's right. This should be informative. http://jsfiddle.net/ProggerPete/WADsy/1/. If you are wanting just the li elements then getElementsByTagName could be a better option. (Assuming your lists aren't nested.)

Comment: Could also use the native `.children` then put the code in a function for unsupported browsers. Like: `var list_items=(list.children || children(list))`

Comment: I would not use *children* on the general web, it is a proprietary property that has been included in HTML5. it is not well supported by older browsers.

Comment: @Peter Wilkinson: Is it possible to use `getElementsByTagName` to grab the `<li>` elements in a specific list? Because I have more than one list on the page.

Comment: I think the desired result here would be a `nodeType` check for `1`. Though uncommon, nodes such as comment nodes would still be picked up by your code.

Comment: @inquisitive_web_developer: Yep. http://jsfiddle.net/ProggerPete/WADsy/3/. The only thing that will cause you grief is lists within lists. If you want to support that then you'll need to write a function to filter out the #text nodes from childNodes.

Comment: @ Michael - *"The childNodes, depending on the browser used"* Um...what browsers are you aware of that *don't* include text nodes? That would be a massive violation of even the original DOM spec.

Comment: @RobG: `children` has almost universal support. What browsers are you referring to?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder—geeze, that was over 6 years ago, before the iPhone 5! MDN's [*compatibility table*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) provides a hint. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: Gah!! I misread the date/time on that comment! I read it as August of last year! Sorry about that. (My eyes really are going...) (I love the "Edge: 38" compatibility note. I'm quite sure Edge supported `children` from day 1, as IE8 supported it. But people are weird with version numbers now, the first Edge could well have been 38...)

Answer (score 3):

You have text nodes there.

You can skip them while iterating with...

```
for (var i = 0, length = list_items.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (list_items[i].nodeType != 1) {
        continue;
    }
    // Any code here that accesses list_items[i] will sure to be an element.
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/Br8hV/).

Alternatively, you could do it in a more functional way...

```
list_items = Array.prototype.filter.call(list_items, function(element) { 
                 return element.nodeType == 1;
             });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/qmDrt/).

You must use convert it to a proper array to use the `filter()` method. `childNodes` property returns a `NodeList` object.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, the childNode count inclues the text nodes, generated by the whitespace between the <li> elements.

```
<ul id="list"><li>milk</li><li>butter</li><li>eggs</li><li>orange juice</li><li>bananas</li></ul>
```

That will give you 5 childNodes because it omits the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Text nodes are included in the child nodes count. To get the proper value, you'd need to strip out text nodes, or make sure they are not in your code. Any white space between code is considered a space and a text node, so your count is the total number of text nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I cobbled together a solution for this that I like.  (I got the idea from [this blog post](http://www.sitepoint.com/children-of-the-dom/).)

1) First I get the number of child elements nodes by using:

```
nodeObject.childElementCount;
```

2) Then I wrote a function that will return any child element node by index number.  I did this by using firstElementChild and nextElementSibling in a for loop.

```
function getElement(x, parentNode){
    var item = parentNode.firstElementChild
    for (i=0;i<x;i++){
         item = item.nextElementSibling;
    }
    return item;
}
```

This returns the child element I need for anything I want to pull from it.  It skips the problem with childNodes retuning all the different nodes that are not helpful when trying to parse just the elements.  I am sure someone more experienced than me could clean this up. But I found this so helpful that I had to post it.

Answer (score 0):

Use obj.children instead.

```
var list = document.getElementById('list');
var list_items = list.children;
alert(list_items.length);
```

The difference between this children and childNodes, is that childNodes contain all nodes, including text nodes and comment nodes, while children only contain element nodes.
from w3schools.