# How do you count child nodes in HTML DOM using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom

**Question: How do you count child nodes in HTML DOM  using Javascript?**

Here is my code;

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>First p Element.</p>
  <p>Second p Element.</p>
</div>

alert(document.getElementById("myDiv").childNodes.length);
//5
```

But i think there are 4 child nodes...

**my explanation:**

```
<p></p> (1st) //Element node
First p Element. (2nd) // text node
<p></p> (3rd) //Element node
Second p Element. (4th) // text node
```

**i would like to know where the 5th child node is coming from?**

And about the whitespace being considered to be a **text node** , **When is an element considered to have no child node ?**

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072423/why-does-childnodes-return-a-number-larger-than-i-expect

Comment: @Pugazh: Good find.

Comment: Re your edit: Questions on Stack Overflow are not meant to be moving targets. Once a question has answers, editing it to ask an entirely new, follow-on question is not how SO works.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder... My bad...won't happen again.. But could you please answer my last question about elements considered to have no child nodes ?

Comment: I haven't gotten into the details (the details are likely [in here somewhere](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html)), but fundamentally, `<p></p>` has a `childNodes.length` of 0, `<p> </p>` has a `childNodes.length` of 1 (where that space could be one space, a bunch of spaces, a newline, etc., as HTML treats all of those the same).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks alot , that is exactly all i needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are five:

1. Text node containing whitespace (between the opening `<div>` and the first `<p>`)
2. `p` element
3. Text node containing whitespace (between the `</p>` and the following `<p>`)
4. `p` element
5. Text node containing whitespace (between the last `</p>` and the `</div>`)

Note that *neither* of the two text nodes you mentioned in your list is in `myDiv`'s `childNodes`. They're in the `childNodes` of the `p` elements inside `myDiv`. `childNodes` only includes *direct children* of an element, not its indirect descendants.

Illustration:

```js
var nodes = document.getElementById("myDiv").childNodes;
var n, node;
for (n = 0; n < nodes.length; ++n) {
  node = nodes[n];
  if (node.nodeType == 3) { // text node
    console.log(node.nodeName + ": " + JSON.stringify(node.nodeValue));
  } else {
    console.log(node.nodeName);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <p>First p Element.</p>
  <p>Second p Element.</p>
</div>
```